# Calculate UIWebView Height in UITableViewCell with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiwebview, autolayout

I tried to follow *autolayout* from [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) website and would like to calculate the `UITableViewCell` *height*.

However, the *height* of `UIWebView` will not be calculated until it is finish loading the html content with `UIWebViewDelegate`.

In such case, I always have a wrong height on the `UITableViewCell`. in following `UITableViewDelegate` methods

```
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
- tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

I would like to know how do I calculate the *height* of a `UITableViewCell` with `UIWebView` inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you're rendering a UIWebView inside your UITableViewCell ?

Comment: I get the HTML comment from disqus API, And I would like to display them in the HTML format. (also called rich text format) It contains link, highlight and etc.

Comment: Have you tried looking at how to use NSAttributedText for a UILabel to render your HTML content ?

Comment: Hello Zhang, Yes. For instance : https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText , However it does not provide features like hyperlink. Or do you have any suggestion on my problem ? thanks

Comment: I think you need to put the attributed text into a UITextView for hyperlinked texts.

Comment: so you suggest that using uitextview + NSAttributedText for handling the richtext format instead of UIWebView, right?

Comment: I suggest avoiding dynamic cell height all together after going down that route myself. iOS isn't like web programming where it handles the height update given the content. iOS is the opposite, you tell it the height before you render the content and that works against asynchronous data being pulled from a server. I feel that UITableView is a list of summary not a list of full detail pages. Viewing the full content should be done inside a "detail" page upon tapping on each row of the table view.

Comment: I understand your point about life cycle on iOS, especially on UITableView. However, I found quite a lot of app could do what I said. e.g. Facebook, engadget, 9gag .... That's why I wonder how do they handle my case. According your point + what people talk about in SO, I believe putting WebView in a TableCell is not a good habit.

Comment: I hear Facebook does a lot of optimizations behind the scenes on the server end and then passes it to the client app, not sure if that's true. My own observation shows that parsing HTML text for each UITableViewCell has staggering performance as you scroll, the cells themselves take half a second to 1 second pause before it scrolls, giving your table view a jerky look.

Comment: I agree with the performance as well. I try to look into the uitextview see if I could handle something similar. Thank you very much for your help.